# Location of MySQL log files on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I would like to delete the MySQL `ib_logfile` but do not know where the files are located on my machine.

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log files are usually located at `/var/log/`. MySQL server log files are usually named like `mysql.SOMETHING`.

For ib_logfiles, also check `/var/lib/mysql`.